# Did the world suffer a general economic decline in 1870?

Tags: 19th-century, economy

Last year the [World Bank reported](https://www.worldbank.org/en/news/press-release/2020/06/08/covid-19-to-plunge-global-economy-into-worst-recession-since-world-war-ii) that :

> According to World Bank forecasts, the global economy will shrink by 5.2% this year. That would represent the deepest recession since the Second World War, with the largest fraction of economies experiencing declines in per capita output since 1870, the World Bank says in its June 2020 Global Economic Prospects.

[Wikipedia has a list of economic crises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_economic_crises#19th_century), and it reports 2 starting in 1873, the [Great Depression of British Agriculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Depression_of_British_Agriculture) (1873–1896) and the [Long Depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Depression) (1873–1896).  There is no mention of 1870.

Did a large number of "economies" (I presume that is synonymous with countries) suffer an economic decline in 1870?  Or is the world bank referring to 1873?

Comment: Looking further down the article it says "_How deep will the COVID-19 recession be? An investigation of 183 economies over the period 1870-2021 offers a historical perspective on global recessions._" which suggests to me that 1870 is simply the starting point for their analysis.

Comment: In contexts like this, the dates are usually chosen based on availability of data rather than "last time it was this bad".

Comment: Tweaked the title. "generalised decline" might be a term for a recession where you're from, but it isn't here in the US, and I at least was confused.

Comment: The Franco Prussian war changed the imperialist world system and created Germany. It is commonly used as a start for the long 20th century.